# AngularMaterial - MatRipple is displaying ripple outside table row

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use `matRipple` in table row on click. However, ripple effect is flowing outside particular table row `tr` .However, it is working for `table  td.` The effect should be within boundary as it happens in `MatButton`.

Link:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-2ahyd7?file=app/app.component.html

```
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr matRipple  (click)="callalert()">
          <td>sss</td>
          <td>ssssss</td>
        </tr>
        <tr matRipple  (click)="callalert()">
          <td>sss</td>
          <td>ssssss</td>
        </tr>
        <tr matRipple  (click)="callalert()">
          <td>sss</td>
          <td>ssssss</td>
        </tr>
        <tr matRipple  (click)="callalert()">
          <td>sss</td>
          <td>ssssss</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11883

A potential workaround using `mat-table`

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="items">
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" matRipple></mat-row>
</table>
```

You could also create a `.ripple` CSS class and apply that class to the rows you want to ripple:

```
.ripple {
  background-position: center;
  transition: background 0.8s;
}
.ripple:hover {
  background: white radial-gradient(circle, transparent 1%, white 1%) center/15000%;
}
.ripple:active {
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background 0s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, I am not using mat-table here, instead I am using mat-ripple only inside a table(not Mat-table). However, matRipple is working fine on table td (Above Stackblitz)

Comment: @Mahi - Hmm. You might have to use `mat-table` to get things working correctly. Is that not an option?

Comment: I can't remove my current table code . I am wondering its working for table td but not for table tr.why? If any work around in the current scenario is available, can you help me with that.

Comment: @Mahi - I understand. I edited the answer with a custom CSS class you could use.

Comment: But Ripple Effect is not visible as it is for matRipple. Please have  a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-2ahyd7?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: @Mahi - you need to add the `ripple` class to the rows. Something like: `<tr class='ripple' ...>`

Comment: I did so but effect is not same as matRipple . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-2ahyd7?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: @Mahi - I updated the CSS. You can also fiddle with the colors used to fine-tune the effect.

Comment: Updated CSS one more time to get as close to the standard effect as possible